# Some confusion about LinkedList type args in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I compiled it with gcc 5.1.

```c
typedef struct lnode{
    int data;
    struct lnode *next;
} lnode;

void Traverse(lnode *list); //print all node
lnode* Last(lnode* list);  //locate the last
lnode* newNode(int value); 
void Merge(lnode* old,lnode* new); 

void Traverse(lnode *list)
{
    while(list != NULL)
    {
    printf("%d ",list->data);
    list= list->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
lnode* Last(lnode* list)
{
    while(list->next != NULL)    
    list = list->next;
        return list;
}
lnode* newNode(int value)
{
    lnode* l = malloc(sizeof(lnode));
    l->data = value;
    l->next = NULL;
    return l;
}
void Merge(lnode* old,lnode* new)
{
    Last(old)->next = new;
}
int main()
{
    lnode* Alist = newNode(1);  
    Merge(Alist,newNode(2));  
    Merge(Alist,newNode(3)); 
    Traverse(Alist);  
    Traverse(Alist);   
}
```

The function Merge and Traverse both have  args of (`lnode*`) type,
but why **Merge** changed *Alist* but **Traverse** did not? 
What should be the most standard function？

Comment: See `Last(old)->next = new;` in `Merge` -- that is adding a new node at the end. `Traverse` does nothing similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Merge` will obviously change the **Alist** as it adds a new node at the end of the list.

`Traverse` is just accessing and printing the data value of the nodes.

Comment: But  `Traverse ` did `list= list->next` why this code  did not change  **Alist** ?

Comment: the "list" acts as temporary parameter passed to a function Traverse() which holds the address of the node. "list = list->next" is just a mechanism to get the next address to be accessed and not modify the actual Alist

Comment: I can understand your intuition as the Merge function has been written in the same manner, but check that it actually sets the next of the last node with a address of the new node

Comment: So, the best way, I would suggest printing values of the variables, try some logging and debugging to understand the concept better

Comment: Re "*why this code did not change Alist ?*", C passes by copy. This means that changing a parameter (e.g. `list`) has no effect on the caller. However, if a pointer is passed to a function, the function can change something to which the caller has access. So while changing `list` has no effect on the caller, changing `list->data` or `list->next` can since you're not changing `list` but that to which `list `points.